# Getting Stackoverflow in netty Encoder

Tags: java, netty

I want to send a custom message of my own before sending actual one, the first time channel is initialized. I have:

```
public class MyClientInitializerFactory extends ClientInitializerFactory {

@Override
protected void initChannel(Channel ch) {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(new EncoderTwo());
    pipeline.addLast(new EncoderOne());
}
}
```

EncoderOne:

```
public class EncoderOne extends MessageToMessageEncoder<Object> {

@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = "ABCD".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.buffer(bytes.length);
    Channel channel = ctx.channel();
    channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
    out.add(msg); // retaining original message for further processing
    ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
}
```

EncoderTwo processes actual message and sends it down the wire but my message never gets there. When I try to send anything these lines are executed over and over again until I get StackOverflow:

```
 ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.buffer(bytes.length);
 Channel channel = ctx.channel();
 channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: So in first encoder you add your actual input to list of output objects passed to next encoder, right? Why are you doing so? What's type of `msg`?

Comment: it's a string. I add it to the list because I need to process it there and send after processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you call `channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);` in the encoder which means it will start to flow through the pipeline from the tail again and so end up in your encoder again. So either remove the encoder first before calling it or call `ctx.writeAndFlush(...)`

An alternative would be to also just add the `byteBuf` to the out `List` as well directly an then call `flush()`.

Comment: That works, thanks! Wouldn't adding byteBuf to the out List pass it to the next encoder together with the original message?